# Display multiple timezones with only one function

Tags: jquery

I would like to display different time zones for different countries. The thing is that I can't get it to work like I want to.

I have a data attribute called `data-hour`. This could be plus/minus any number. In the function `update` I get the value with `var AddHours = $('.hours').data("hours");`.

If I just wanted to display one time, I could simply use something like `date.setHours(date.getHours() + 3);` and it would show the current time +3 hours. I have modified this to `date.setHours(date.getHours() AddHours);`, but it shows nothing. Obviously I have done something wrong. But what?

Thank you.

Code:

```
<!--Country One-->
<p id="C_one" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
    <span class="hours" data-hours="+4"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Two-->
<p id="C_two" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
    <span class="hours" data-hours="-1"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Three-->
<p id="C_three" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
    <span class="hours" data-hours="+2"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<script>
var $hOut = $('.hours'),
    $mOut = $('.minutes'),
    $sOut = $('.seconds');

function update(){
    var AddHours = $('.hours').data("hours");
    var date = new Date();

    date.setHours(date.getHours() AddHours);

    var hours = date.getHours();
    hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;

    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;

    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    $hOut.text(hours);
    $mOut.text(minutes);
    $sOut.text(seconds);
} 

update();
window.setInterval(update, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as below.

Loop over `$('.TextCenter')` and find `.hours`, `.minutes`, `.seconds` inside it. using `$(this).find`.

Update your `date` as `date = new Date(date.getTime() + (AddHours * 60 * 60 * 1000));`.

```js
function update() {

  $('.TextCenter').each(function() {
    var $hOut = $(this).find('.hours'),
      $mOut = $(this).find('.minutes'),
      $sOut = $(this).find('.seconds');

    var AddHours = $hOut.data("hours");
    var date = new Date();

    date = new Date(date.getTime() + (AddHours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    //date.setHours(date.getHours());

    var hours = date.getHours();
    hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;

    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;

    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    $hOut.text(hours);
    $mOut.text(minutes);
    $sOut.text(seconds);
  });
}

update();
window.setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Country One-->
<p id="C_one" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="+4"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Two-->
<p id="C_two" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="-1"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Three-->
<p id="C_three" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="+2"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Karan - this worked like a charm! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the following line:

```
date.setHours(date.getHours() AddHours);
```

to

```
date.setHours(date.getHours(), AddHours);
```

[Add a comma.]

And if you dont have any jQuery library attached, then add it to the scripts.

The solution will work. Like the one below:

```js
var $hOut = $('.hours'),
  $mOut = $('.minutes'),
  $sOut = $('.seconds');

function update() {
  var AddHours = $('.hours').data("hours");
  var date = new Date();

  date.setHours(date.getHours(), AddHours);

  var hours = date.getHours();
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;

  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;

  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

  $hOut.text(hours);
  $mOut.text(minutes);
  $sOut.text(seconds);
}

update();
window.setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Country One-->
<p id="C_one" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="+4"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Two-->
<p id="C_two" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="-1"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>

<!--Country Three-->
<p id="C_three" class="TextCenter NoMargin ClockUnit">
  <span class="hours" data-hours="+2"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: This didn't work. It shows the same time for each country. But thank you for trying anyway.

Comment: But the code had bugs, the issue raised by You, is that current code could not even display anything in the output, it just displays a blank screen

Comment: There was syntax error in your code, @NielsHermann, so I corrected that